# Azure APIM new developer portal not working

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to publish the Developer portal of my Azure API Management, but for some reason it's not working.

Here's what I do:

1. Click the Portal overview menu item on the left (under Developer portal)
2. Click Publish -> Yes
3. Click Enable CORS -> Yes
4. Wait ~5 minutes
5. Click the Developer portal link at the top of the page
   The new portal opens, and shows the 3 dots sign of loading. After a few seconds I get the following error:

[image: Developer portal error]

And that's it, basically...

Now, the legacy portal works just fine, so I don't think this is a problem with the APIM settings itself.
I don't know if it's relevant, but the APIM is deployed in an external VNet. No problem whatsoever in accessing it using Postman etc. In addition, I made sure port 3443 is open.

What could be the problem here? How can I view the new developer portal?

**EDIT:**
I've done a little digging on the client side, and found out the browser calls the following URL which returns 404:

https://myapimname.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myapimname/contentTypes/document/contentItems/<some_nasty_guid>?api-version=2019-12-01

The error appears just after this failure.

Any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed version of developer portal is just bunch of json files sitting in the storage. These json files are called content items and they define the look of your developer portal. Although I don't know why but for you one of these content items is missing and that's why you are getting 404.

Possible solution:
Normally in case of some problems, what you do is you go to the developer portal and click 'reset content':

[image]

This operation will just load default json files and reset everything. But since developer portal is not loading for you I assume you cannot do that?

So unless you can afford creating new APIM and moving everything there, you can be a little adventurous and make a use of [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/contentitem). You go there and list all of the content items with content type id equals to `document`. Content type is just a parent for content item. And according to your error one of the content items with type `document` is missing.

You list those and compare to the content items from "healthy" apim instance and try to find out what is missing. If you find a difference you can try to add missing content item using the same rest api. You do that and it might just work. Good luck.

PS. [Here](https://jsonblob.com/6bbe77ce-badf-11eb-a603-0b4d4caf957a) you can find my json file - the default content items with `document` content type.

Comment: Actually resetting did the trick... Thanks!